# ng-repeat toggle slide, but others should be close

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below code for `slide toggle`, it

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.searchitems track by $index">
    <div class="quickinfo-overlap"> Content here...
        <a class="btn-link" ng-click="$ctrl.quickinfoToggle(item)">quick info</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am using `ng-repeat`, so it is showing list, I want others list should be close or quickinfo `false`. so can I do?

This is the controller code:

```
function listingController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.quickinfo = false;
    vm.quickinfoToggle = function(event) {
        event.quickinfo = !event.quickinfo;
    };
};
```

Comment: can you please post your controller code as well or working snippet

Comment: Below is my full code,

        <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.searchitems track by $index">

            <div class="quickinfo-overlap">
                Content here...
               <a class="btn-link" ng-click="$ctrl.quickinfoToggle(item)">quick info</a>
    </div>
</div>
function listingController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.quickinfo = false;
  vm.quickinfoToggle = function(event){
      event.quickinfo = !event.quickinfo;
  };
};

Comment: For legibility, please add your code in question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.searchitems track by $index">
    <div class="quickinfo-overlap"> Content here...
        <a class="btn-link" ng-click="$ctrl.quickinfoToggle(item,$index)">quick info</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        DIV that needs to be toggled on click
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function listingController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.toggleList = [];
    for(var i=0;i< $scope.searchitems.length;i++)
        $scope.toggleList[i] = false;

    vm.quickinfoToggle = function(event,index) {
    for(var i=0;i< $scope.toggleList.length;i++)
        $scope.toggleList[i] = false;

    $scope.toggleList[index] = true
        event.quickinfo = !event.quickinfo;
    };
};
```

Comment: But other lists are not closing. It is working same.

Answer (score 0):

while looping with `ng-repeat` to show the items, set `ng-show`:

```
 <div class="quickinfo slide-toggle" ng-show="quickinfo == 1" ng-cloak>
   Content here ....           
 </div>
 <a class="btn-link" ng-click="quickinfo = 1">quick info</a>
```

Of course `1` is not fixed number, it should be unique to each item, like the index or id of the item.
The idea is when clicking the `quickinfo` link you assigned the clicked item's id not assign `true\false` to the `quickinfo`, and in `ng-show` check if the current id assigned to `quickinfo` is the same as this item id (or index).
Of course variable names can be changed.